# Moving decimal places to the right in PostgreSQL when querying

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't figure out how to move decimal places to the right & keep getting errors. I want to display the numbers in this format -- 1528.1 -- instead of 0.15281e4

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
SELECT * FROM movie_revenues
WHERE international_takings IS NOT NULL
AND international_takings AS TO_CHAR (0.00000, '1.1111')
ORDER BY international_takings DESC 
LIMIT 3;
```

[image: Code and table output]

Comment: 0.15281e4 == 1528.1 , not 1.5281

Comment: Do you just want to display international_takings and not filter by it? If so, you need to select it, not put something in the where clause.

Comment: `international_takings AS TO_CHAR (0.00000, '1.1111')` is invalid SQL to begin with (the WHERE clause requires boolean expressions). You need to do the formatting in the SELECT list.

Comment: This is an issue in your GUI, not in your database. What GUI do you use?

Comment: What is the data type of `international_takings`?

Comment: This `TO_CHAR (0.00000, '1.1111')  1 .1111` should be `TO_CHAR (0.00000, '9.9999') .0000` or if you want the leading zero `TO_CHAR (0.00000, '0.9999') 0.0000`. Still I'm with @FrankHeikens and you are seeing formatting by the GUI.

Comment: thanks for your help!! @FrankHeikens I'm using https://www.elephantsql.com/

Comment: @keab28: That's a cloud solution for database hosting. Ask them how to use their GUI and how to get rid of this behaviour in this GUI. Or use another GUI on your own machine to connect to the remote database. I use Navicat and DataGrip, non of these has problems with large numbers.